# Phonegap marshmallow - Camea permissions

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have the following code that takes the user to the gallery to choose an image and upload it.

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, function(message) {
    }, {
        quality: 50,
        targetWidth: 512,
        targetHeight: 512,
        destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
        correctOrientation: true
    });
```

This code is working perfect but when i'm testing it on android with api of 23 (marshmallow) it ALWAYS asking the user to allow the permission to access the gallery phone.

"Allow my app to access photos, media and files on your device?"

Even if the user press Allow (and it works), next time the user will get 
this message again.

I'm using phonegap 6.3.0

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: do you have the latest version of cordova-plugin-camera?

Comment: Yes, version 2.3.0

Comment: hmm, can you try with the previous version (2.2.0)?